# how to copy shortcode into a block?

Tags: block-editor

I intended to copy the following content

```
[quiz]
[question]how to create a remote branch?[/question]
[answer][/answer]
[/quiz]
```

But it was automatically put into a shortcode block which I don't want. I want to put it into a pragraph block. How to change this? Thank you.

[image]
This image shows I was originally typing the content in a paragraph block.

[image]
This image shows when pasting, it becomes a shortcode block.

Comment: I'm not sure what difference it makes, can you clarify? Unless the quiz shortcode only generates inline tags, what you're asking for makes no sense. Keep in mind this stack is a technical stack aimed at developers/programmers, not end users, this question should be asked on the .org support forums instead

Comment: I will show you screenshots

Comment: I understood the mechanics, the screenshots confirm that, but i don't understand why you would want it? What's the problem that putting the shortcodes in the paragraph block solves?